# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygn'

Tags: python-3.x, conda

Firstly, I just want to mention that this is my first post and I'm a python noob. Also, I realize my post title is very much like many others already on stackoverflow, but alas, have been unable to find anything that is of help to me.

Problem:
I'm unable to import the pygn module, despite having installed it in my virtual environment.

Error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygn'`

Repro Steps:
1. `conda create --name gn`
2. `activate gn`
3. `conda install pip`
4. `pip install pygn`
5. `conda list` to verify package was successfully installed in gn env (it was)
6. `python gracenote.py`
7. `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gracenote.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygn, json
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygn'`

Any help in resolving this error would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pypi has [this entry](https://pypi.org/project/pygn/) for `pygn`, which actually refers to a project named [`pyg`](https://gitlab.com/mcepl/pyg). It looks like you'll need to manually include [this repo](https://github.com/cweichen/pygn) as a part of what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply; so, just to be sure I understand, the issue isn't my workflow, but rather that for this particular module, I'll need to download it manually?

Comment: Your workflow includes downloading a module that has the same name as what you're trying to use. I'd say that's a problem in your workflow. You should always check out the installation instructions for modules you want to use.

Comment: I had forgotten that the documentation said to just copy the file into the root directory and import it from there.  Guess that's what I'll do.